# Why is this equal to $\cos x$?

Tags: real-analysis

In analysis I, my professor wrote that:

$\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + o(x^4)$

I would like to know why that's true.

Comment: Taylor series for $\cos$.

Comment: BTW, your professor could have written $o(x^5)$ instead of $o(x^4).$

Comment: Heck, he could have written $O(x^6)$.

Comment: She could have written $O(x^7)$, but she would have been wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Look up Taylor/Maclaurin series:

The idea is that we can represent many "nice" functions in terms of a power series.

That is a series of the form $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(x-x_0)^n$$

It turns out that the series representation for $\cos (x)$ about $x=0$ is

$1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\text{higher terms}$.

Comment: Convergent Taylor series and finite Taylor polynomials are related but distinct concepts and shouldn't be muddled like this. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308992/why-doesnt-a-taylor-series-converge-always

Answer (score 1):

i'll post this as an answer because i can't comment yet.

The expression given by The Professor is a taylor expansion. A particular class indeed, called Maclaurin expansion. In this link

http://blogs.ubc.ca/infiniteseriesmodule/units/unit-3-power-series/taylor-series/the-maclaurin-expansion-of-cosx/

you'll see a video explaining the thing.